# Transforming three arrays to one with values/keys

Tags: php

***Note: The arrays below are not 3 different arrays. They are part of 1 variable: $mainArray;***

Sample Array 1 (Keys):

```
[0] => Apartments
[1] => Apartments
[2] => Apartments
[3] => Houses
[4] => Houses
[5] => Houses
[6] => Suites
[7] => Suites
[8] => Exclusive
[9] => Exclusive
[10] => SuperB
```

Sample Array 2 (Values):

```
[0] => Apartment Value1
[1] => Apartment Value2
[2] => Apartment Value3
[3] => Houses Value 1
[4] => Houses Value 2
[5] => Houses Value 3
[6] => Suites Value 1
[7] => Suites Value 2
[8] => Exclusive Value 1
[9] => Exclusive Value 2
[10] => SuperB Value 1
```

Sample Array 3 (Values):

```
[0] => Apartment Value1
[1] => Apartment Value2
[2] => Apartment Value3
[3] => Houses Value 1
[4] => Houses Value 2
[5] => Houses Value 3
[6] => Suites Value 1
[7] => Suites Value 2
[8] => Exclusive Value 1
[9] => Exclusive Value 2
[10] => SuperB Value 1
```

My desired result is:

```
$array[$key] = array($array2,$array3);
```

Sample Result:

```
[Apartments] => array(rows 0-3 from Array #2, 0-3 from Array #3);
[Houses] => array(rows 3-5 from Array #2, 3-5 from Array #3);
[Exclusive] => array(rows 6-7 from Array #2, 6-7 from Array #3);
[Suites] => array(rows 8-9 from Array #2, 8-9 from Array #3);
[SuperB] => array(row 10 from Array #2, 10 from Array #3);
```

Therefore becoming a dimensional array with keys.

For this question, lets always assume that the three arrays hold exactly the same amount of rows. The difference is, I want to transform the first array (keys), to hold the other two arrays as a dimensional array.

Comment: Can you show us how you want the final array to look? Maybe it makes this easier to understand

Comment: I've updated the question with a "Sample Result" block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you desire. Let me know if i can help you more about this.

```
<?php
    $mainArray = [
        ["Apartments","Apartments","Apartments","Houses","Houses","Houses","Suites","Suites","Exclusive","Exclusive","SuperB"],
        ["Apartment Value1","Apartment Value2","Apartment Value3","Houses Value 1","Houses Value 2","Houses Value 3","Suites Value 1","Suites Value 2","Exclusive Value 1","Exclusive Value 2","SuperB Value 1"],
        ["Apartment Value1","Apartment Value2","Apartment Value3","Houses Value 1","Houses Value 2","Houses Value 3","Suites Value 1","Suites Value 2","Exclusive Value 1","Exclusive Value 2","SuperB Value 1"]
    ];

    if(count($mainArray[0]) != count($mainArray[1]) || count($mainArray[0]) != count($mainArray[2])) {
        throw new Exception("Arrays are not the same size");
    }

    $resultArray = [];
    $count = count($mainArray[0]);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if(!isset($resultArray[$mainArray[0][$i]])) {
            $resultArray[$mainArray[0][$i]] = array($mainArray[1][$i], $mainArray[2][$i]);
        } else {
            $resultArray[$mainArray[0][$i]][] = $mainArray[1][$i];
            $resultArray[$mainArray[0][$i]][] = $mainArray[2][$i];
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($resultArray, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes.. Looks like what I need. Only thing is that all arrays are in one variable. They are not separated

Comment: I've updated the code, it should work know as expected :)

Comment: Looks superb! However, the arrays are not 3 separate arrays.. They are in $mainArray which holds 3 arrays.

Comment: I've updated the code once more :D If your arrays in $mainArray have keys other than 0, 1 and 2 just change 0, 1 and 2 in my code with key for keys array, key for first values array, key for second values array like in that order. I've also added a simple `if` statement so the code won't execute if all three arrays are not the same size.

Comment: That seems to be the correct answer! However, when I print_r($mainArray), it looks like nothing has changed..

Comment: Well $mainArray still holds the same value after this code because this only creates new variables using values from $mainArray. You can unset($mainArray) or set it to null if you don't need in anymore.
Just mark my answer as accepted so the others know that the problem is solved :)

Comment: I see.. Would something like this work? Check the edited question

Comment: Well do you want the script to create new variables by keys array from $mainArray or you want the new values to be stored in an array like key => array(value1, value2)? Pozdrav

Comment: I'd like for it to be stored like key => array(value1, value2) :)

Comment: I think the temp solution is fine as it is.. However, is it the most optimal way doing "$tmpArray[$mainArray[0][$i]][]" ?

Comment: Ok i think the updated code should be final. The "merge" result is stored in $resultArray

Comment: Perfect! Hvala majstor!